# How can I add a timeout to a a `multi` in Smallrye Mutiny?

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

In Smallrye Mutiny, I can add a timeout to a `Uni` using something like:

```java
uni.ifNoItem().after(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).fail()
```

I searched for a similar API for a `Multi` but couldn't find any. Features I would have expected are:

- do something if no item has been emitted for some time
- do something if the `Multi` has not completed within a given time

Can this be achieved somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately Multi does not expose such an API yet. There is an issue about that (https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-mutiny/issues/11). It has not been implemented yet because we are lacking of use cases and clear understanding of how it will be used. Thus, I’m very interested to hear about your case. If you could comment on the issue, it would be awesome.